# Unable to run 32-bit exe in windows containers

Tags: docker, windows-installer, 32bit-64bit, windows-container

I'm trying to build a docker image (using mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/runtime) which executes a - 32-bit - MSi installer silently to install an app. While this had been working in the recent past on the host VM (windows Server 2019), it has stopped working all of a sudden. The problem seems to be related with a newer windows update or security patch.

Worked on v17763.678
Doesn't work on v17763.737 or later.

Does anyone know of any recent changes related to this that restricts running 32-bit apps in windows containers?

Answer (score 3):

I finally figured out the problem. So for whoever runs into this or similar issue, I hope this will save them a lot of time and trouble.

Apparently, Microsoft pushed out an update on Feb. 11, 2020 (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4542617/you-might-encounter-issues-when-using-windows-server-containers-with-t) that created the issue of 32-bit programs silently not starting inside windows containers.

I had to update both, the VM with a later update as well use a newer base image for my docker image to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Right now the containers doesn't run 32bit application.
So either upgrade application to 64 bit or use other solutions like Azure App Service or Azure VM